# How do I access the root folder of the phone's internal storage using the PC?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, storage

How can I access my internal phone storage on PC? I mean the root storage, the path. So that I could put back the lost app on the system storage.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a closer look into [adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), which gives you a command shell directly on the device. Using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb), you could do the following:

```
# copy your file to the device
adb push my.apk /data/local/my.apk
# open a shell on the device, and become root
adb shell
su
# now check where and how your /system partition is mounted, and make it writeable
mount | grep system
> /dev/block/stl12 /system ext4 ro,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/stl12 /system
# copy your .apk file to the system apps
cp /data/local/my.apk /system/app
# remount /system back to read-only
mount -o ro,remount /dev/block/stl12 /system
```

In above example, you need of course to replace `my.apk` with the correct name. Same applies to the mount data: The line starting with `>` is just an example, which might (and most likely will) not match your device. So carefully check the output of `mount | grep system` to use the correct values here.

If you don't have ADB installed yet, please follow the information given in the [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), which also points to installation instructions and more.